# Trigonometric identity. How can I prove that $\sin A = 2\sin\frac{A}2\cos\frac{A}2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I prove that $\sin A = 2\sin\frac{A}2\cos\frac{A}2$ ?

My failed take on this matter is:
$$
\sin A = 
\sin\frac{A}2 + \sin\frac{A}2 = 2\sin\Big(\frac{\frac{A}2+\frac{A}2}2\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{\frac{A}2-\frac{A}2}2\Big)=
2\sin\Big(\frac{\frac{2A}2}2\Big)\cos\frac02 =
2\sin\frac{A}2
$$
where $\cos\frac02 = \cos0 = 1$

Comment: It seems like you're invoking a rule like $\color{red}{\sin(x+y) = \sin(x) + \sin(y)}$ in the first line.  This is **incorrect**.  Try it with $x = y = \frac{\pi}{2}$ to see why.

Comment: Do you know the addition formula for sine?

Comment: $\sin(A)\not= \sin(A/2)+\sin(A/2)$ this is basically the double angle identity for sine.

Comment: (Still upvoting, because you have included the work you've done so far)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all $$\sin x\neq \sin (x/2)+\sin (x/2)$$
In fact $$\sin (a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b$$
Substitute $a=b=x/2$  to get $$\sin x= 2\sin (x/2)\cos (x/2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Your first step is wrong because
$\sin(x)$ is not a linear function so: $$\sin x \ne \sin(\frac{x}{2})+\sin(\frac{x}{2})$$

Answer (score 0):

In your work, you used the sum-to-product formula, $$\sin\frac{A}2 + \sin\frac{A}2 = 2\sin\Big(\frac{\frac{A}2+\frac{A}2}2\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{\frac{A}2-\frac{A}2}2\Big),$$

which is correct. The mistake is that $$\sin A\ne\sin\frac{A}2 + \sin\frac{A}2$$

You can still use the sum-to-product formula.

$$\sin A + \sin 0 = 2\sin\Big(\frac{A+0}2\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{A-0}2\Big),$$